# How to set the badge to track on all sites

Tags: support, badges

If I wanted to track a certain badge (for example, Enthusiast), how can I set that to all my profiles, on all my sites?

This does not work with the network profile update button.

Comment: You'e pretty unusual in having an account on so many sites. Even allowing for that you're only active by which I mean gaining rep on a few of them so you're not really making progress on badges other than enthusiast.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed. The badges to track are per site. And that is understandable since you can have earned that badge on one or more sites already. What badge should be tracked then?

I think it is fine this way, but if you feel like it, you can make it a feature request.